# Ошибка при запуске приложения: signing for "project" requires a development team

Tags: ios, xcode

Написал небольшое приложение в xcode и решил протестить на айпад. Что за development team? Что с этим делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить аккаунт и выбрать команду. Можно использовать персональный аккаунт,  не оплаченный для разработки. Выбираете `Signing & Capabilities -> Team -> Add an Account -> Добавляете аккаунт -> Регистрируете устройство -> Запускаете на устройстве`.

На устройстве ещё может потребоваться зайти в `настройки -> разработчик -> разрешить запуск приложений от разработчика`.

Насколько помню, на бесплатном аккаунте максимум 3 приложения можно установить и они перестанут запускаться через ~неделю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]